# Angular 4 HttpClient Cannot sent data with POST

Tags: php, angular, post, httpclient

Angular 4.4.4
This is my app component

```
constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
)

this.http.post('/api.php', {name, age}).subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data);
});
```

`api.php    ->    exit(json_encode($_POST));`

Don't receive any data in $_POST

return [];

(`let xmlRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();`
....
 works fine)

I try set header

```
  let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');
```

not work

Sorry for this question but I spent 1 day and still could not find solution.

ps. client and server has same origin.

Comment: Please post your PHP method

Comment: exit(json_encode($_POST))

Comment: I mean, your signature, your method completely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to this.

In PHP, `$_POST` only accept formdata.

With request header 'Content-Type: application/json' you can receive it with `file_get_contents('php://input');`

So

```
$_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to put your parameters into a FormData Object on the Angular side.

```
const params = new FormData();
params.append('para1', 'value1');
params.append('para2', 'value1');
this.http.post('/api.php', params).subscribe(....)
```

Now you can get the parameters on the PHP part of your project with $_POST['para1'] and $_POST['para2'].

I like this solution more than getting all the stuff with file_get_contents, as it looks more straight forward for me.

Answer (score 1):

please try I hope it will help you

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';


@Injectable()
export class LandingService {

    private apiUrl = 'http://localhost:5000/';

  list:any;
  headers : any;
  constructor(private _http: HttpClient){
        this.headers = new Headers();
        this.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  }
     getsearchResponse(searchText){
          this.list ={"sentences":searchText}
          return this._http.post(this.apiUrl+'searchBotsNew',this.list,this.headers)
          .map(res =>res.json())
          .do(data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data)));

      }



}
```

Comment: have u import HttpClientModule in app.module.ts file ?

Comment: yes i did.  requset sending but server dont recive data

Comment: are you using php backend ?